# sdk8 eclipse suddenly stopped

Tags: android, eclipse, sdk

I have been using *sdk 8* for android app development, it has eclipse inbuilt in it, I have jdk 7 installed to my system also. 
I have tried:

1. re installing *jdk*,
2. running eclipse through commandline

But none of them helped. Rre installing eclipse is not an option, as I never had to do so, as it started working as soon as I installed JDK.
It was working properly, but now it won't open!

When I click on the eclipse icon,the *adt* screen appears,as before,but shortly and then vanishes.

Please help me out!

Answer (score 0):

Try installing JDK 1.6 It should help you.